# How to check referral url and re-direct based on that?

Tags: php

I need to check referral url and if it's generated from Facebook redirect the user to a different webpage. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look in [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

You can then use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the hostname, and compare the domain to a list of known Facebook domains.

Beware, the referer isn't required, and isn't always set.  So, don't use it as any kind of security.

Comment: However keep in mind that you can't really rely on this.  This value can be faked by any client easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (stripos(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST), 'facebook') !== FALSE) {
   header('Location: differentwebpage.html');
}
```

Comment: Location headers must contain a full URL, according to the RFCs.  You shouldn't use relative paths, even though they do work generally.

Comment: True 'nuff, but the question is how to detect facebook, not how to redirect.